# i want to get writen values in datagridtextcolumn on clicking button in WPF here is my code

Tags: wpf

xaml code:

```
<DataGrid Margin="37,188,-121,0" Name="DgCompanies" 
          CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          Grid.ColumnSpan="2" SelectionChanged="DgCompanies_SelectionChanged">

      <DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="220"
                                Binding="{Binding name, Mode=TwoWay}"  />

            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Address" Width="220" 
                                Binding="{Binding address, Mode=TwoWay}" />

            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Action" Width="*"  Visibility="Visible">
                   <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                           <DataTemplate>
                                   <Button Name="BtnUpdateCompany" Content="Update"
                                           Click="BtnUpdateCompany_Click"  />
                           </DataTemplate>
                   </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
             </DataGridTemplateColumn>

      </DataGrid.Columns>
```

c#

```
 private void BtnUpdateCompany_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 { 

 }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is there something you tried that you think should work but isn't? A little more detail if you can.

Comment: company ud=new company();

Comment: ud.name= dgcompnis.....???? what cn i do here